# DeWalt Hammer Drill D25023 SDS Plus Rotary Hammer

Tags: powertools

The Drill does not rotate but the hammer works. Is this something a DIY'er can take apart & fix? The drill is almost new so there is very little, if any, wear on the intermal parts. The front end is held on with four screws, I'm wondering if I split that if there are any repairable parts inside?

Comment: Sounds like a major failure. Warranty?

Comment: I'm trying to come up with ways it could fail in this mode, and the only thing I can come up with is that the mode selection knob isn't working.  Does it do the same thing when set "drill only"?

Comment: It most likely is the selection switch needs to be engaged fully or the drill bit isn't seated or locked in completely.

Comment: i agree with isherwood, sounds like the spindle broke.